# loop within a loop Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a loop within a loop and I am totally confused.

```
for i, value in enumerate(len(sections):
    if i not in [17, 24]:

        if (' tax ' in sections[i]
        or ' Tax ' in sections[i]):

            pat=re.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(m) for m in months]), re.M)
            month = pat.search("\n".join(sections[i].splitlines()[0:6]))
            print(month)
```

The problem is that I want to run the loop for all values in `len(sections)` except 17 and 24. The idea is the following: for each section (article), if the word tax or tax is in it, print the month. Everything is working but the lines at the beginning, where I am trying to run the loop except the values 17 and 24.

Cheers,

Comment: You can't enumerate a length. You mean `for i, value in enumerate(sections):`

Comment: The code you posted is full of syntax errors.

Comment: change enumerate(len(section)) to range(len(section)). You can't enumerate an integer

Comment: @ Glostas, I just changed it and it works, cheers

Comment: Don't edit your question to remove the problem you are trying to solve. Either accept the given answer, or delete the question.

Comment: BTW, does `months` change inside that loop? If not, it's _far_ more efficient to compile your regex pattern outside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
for i, value in enumerate(sections):
    if i not in [17, 24]:
        if ' tax ' in sections[i] or ' Tax ' in sections[i]:
            pat = re.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(m) for m in months]), re.M)
            month = pat.search("\n".join(sections[i].splitlines()[0:6]))
            print(month)
```

Comment: Note: `section[i]` is `value`

Answer (score -1):

the syntax : `for ( i,j) in enumerate(mylist)`                          returns at once tuple of two values . the first is the index of an element and the second one is value corresponding to this element. Think about it to rebuild your program.